# Can't get ngx-bootstrap datepicker directive using viewchild

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

## I want to create a datepicker when scroll event happen,it will hide.

1. I refered to [ngx-bootstrap-datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview#hide-on-scroll)
2. It works just fine on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tapugc?file=src/app/ngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts),but not on my application.
3. Here's my code

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="isEditAuth" class="d-flex position-relative">
 <input
    required
    placeholder="請選擇開始時間"
    class="sidebar cursor_pointer"
    type="text"
    formControlName="start_time"
    [ngClass]="{ input_error: eventForm.get('start_time')?.hasError('required') && eventSubmit }"
    [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
    bsDatepicker
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    readonly
    (onShown)="initTime()"
    (onHidden)="hidden('start_time')"
 />
</div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, TemplateRef, AfterViewChecked, HostListener, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-list',
  templateUrl: './event-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-list.component.scss'],
})
export class EventListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
 @ViewChild(BsDatepickerDirective, { static: false }) datepicker!: BsDatepickerDirective;
 @HostListener('window:mousewheel', ['$event'])
 onWindowScroll(event: any) {
    console.log(this.datepicker);
 }
}
```

4. console.log(this.datepicker) always return undefined...

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild(BsDatepickerDirective, { static: false }) datepicker?: BsDatepickerDirective;

  @HostListener('window:mousewheel', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(event: any) {
    datepicker?.close();
  }
```

Comment: Since this.datepicker return undefined.I can't use method which ngx-bootstrap provide like hide().

Comment: try with datepicker?

Comment: datepicker! not skipped undefined but
datepicker? will help you

Comment: I've update my post. Variable datepicker is declared in component .Without using "this",I cant get datepicker value.